# Analyzing Survey data in R after creating raked weights with rake() from the R survey package

Tags: r, rake, survey

What is the proper way to use the raked weights created by the rake() function in the R survey package?

R documentation gives the following example:

```
library(survey)
   data(api)
   dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
   pop.types <- data.frame(stype=c("E","H","M"), Freq=c(4421,755,1018))
   pop.schwide <- data.frame(sch.wide=c("No","Yes"), Freq=c(1072,5122))
   dclus1r<-rake(dclus1, list(~stype,~sch.wide), list(pop.types, pop.schwide))
   svymean(~api00, dclus1r)


            mean     SE
     api00 641.23 23.704
```

But when I use the weights directly, I get a different SE estimate:

```
 apiclus1$rwt<-weights(dclus1r)
   rakeddesign<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~rwt,  fpc=~fpc, weight=~rwt,data=apiclus1)
   svymean(~api00, rakeddesign)


          mean     SE
   api00 641.23 23.806
```

The difference is small in this example, but the difference is very large in other data that I have.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you get after raking is correct and the answer you get by just putting the raked weights into `svydesign` and not telling it they were raked is wrong (but usually not very wrong).

Using `rake` adjusts the weights, and also adds information to the survey design object that allows for correct standard error estimation. Raking adds information (from the population totals that you specify) and this information reduces the standard errors relative to what you'd get if you just happened to have that set of weights.

Raking is done by iterated post-stratification.  Computing standard errors after post-stratification involves subtracting off the post-stratum means from the residuals that will be used in the standard error estimate.  For a raking estimator, this subtraction is done iteratively.

The relevant code (inside `survey::svyrecvar`) looks like

```
            else if (inherits(psvar, "raking")) {
                for (iterations in 1:10) {
                  for (margin in psvar) {
                    psw <- attr(margin, "weights")
                    x <- x - psw * apply(x/psw, 2, ave, margin)
                  }
                }
            }
```

If you are given the raked weights and you know the raking variables, you can tell `svydesign` that the weights have already been raked with the `calibrate.formula` option.

Sometimes, with public-use data collected by someone else, you don't have the raking variables and you have to just pretend the raked weights are the sampling weights.  When you do that, the standard error estimates become slightly larger than they should be.

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful. I tried the command:
'rakeddesign2<-svydesign(id=~dnum,   fpc=~fpc, weight=~rwt,  
                        calibration.formula=~stype+sch.wide,data=apiclus1, nest=TRUE)'  but obtained the same answer as the original. That is 'svymean(~api00, rakeddesign2) gives a mean of 641.23 and SE of 23.806 (same as without the calibration.formula specification). Did I get the syntax wrong?

Comment: Are you using a version of the `survey` package that's new enough to have that  argument to `svydesign`?

Comment: Thanks! everything worked after I updated my survey package. Thanks!!